# Sorting a list alphabetically in a console-app?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am able to manually enter items and then store them into a list. When I do that and then press "2" to view items (which loads the list), they don't sort alphabetically. I've tried a lot of code but nothing has changed.

I am trying to sort alphabetically by name. The way I input data is: name first, then description, then Id. I've tried a CompareTo method with currentItemList.Sort() with no results.

```
private static List<string> ProductTypeList;
private static Dictionary<string, List<Item>> Products;

public class Item: IComparable<Item>
        {
            public string ProductType;
            public string Name;
            public string Description;
            public int Id;

            public Item(string productType, string name, string description, int id)
            {
                ProductType = productType;
                Name = name;
                Description = description;
                Id = id;

                List<Item> itemList;
                if (Products.ContainsKey(productType))
                {
                    itemList = Products[productType];
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductTypeList.Add(productType);
                    itemList = new List<Item>();
                    Products.Add(productType, itemList);
                }
                itemList.Add(this);
            }
            public int CompareTo(Item b)
            {
                // Alphabetic sort name[A to Z]
                return this.Name.CompareTo(b.Name);
            }
         }
```

I have more code (that just displays the current default list I've already created beforehand, and then my menu with switch/case).
**This snippet of code below (in my switch case) is where I believe I should be trying to sort the items, before they display.**

```
case 1: // View Products
Console.Clear();
foreach (var item in currentItemList) <-- error comes from this line
    {
    currentItemList.Sort(); // <--- sort alphabetically, compareTo()
    item.Display();
    }
    break;
```

I have tried using more variations, but with list.Sort() I get a compare error.

```
List<Tool> SortedList = currentToolList.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
Also LINQ with currentToolList.Sort();
```

I get this error: "Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." on this line:

Comment: "but with list.Sort() I get a compare error." you forgot to post the error message and/or stacktrace

Comment: Yeah sorry I lost the error message because I altered my code. The error I get now is: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. On line 104, which is my foreach loop

Comment: `currentItemList.OrderBy(x => x.Name)` doesn't do anything: Linq is lazy; add materialization: `currentItemList = currentItemList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();`. Why do you loop over `currentToolList` if you are going to sort it?

Comment: Yeah I had that line already but for some reason it didn't work. I changed my switch case and now it works when I press a different number. I shouldn't have overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you should *first* sort the list and then *loop over* it:

```
// Sorted representation
var sorted = currentItemList.OrderBy(item => item.Name);

// Time to loop over sorted and Display the items
foreach (var item in sorted)
  item.Display();
```

Very same idea if you want to sort in place:

```
// First sort
currentItemList.Sort((left, right) => 
   StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(left?.Name, right?.Name));

// Then Display:
foreach (var item in currentItemList)
  item.Display();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know this is now 2 hours old (and irrelevant), but could I apply a similar variation to this code when it comes to not allowing duplicate name console inputs/entries?

Comment: @dangoqut132: If you want to get rid of duplicates, have a look at `.DistinctBy(item => item.Name)` or in case of older c# versions `GroupBy(item => item.Name).First()`

Comment: Yeah I was looking at Enumerable.DistinctBy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Sort() method mutates the state of your collection you are currently iterating over which is not allowed.

So you will need to sort the collection before you iterate over it.

Do the sorting outside the foreach block and you should be fine:

```
currentItemList.Sort(); 
foreach (var item in currentItemList) <-- error comes from this line
{

item.Display();
}
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should order items in "foreach" statement like below:

```
foreach (var tool in currentToolList.OrderBy(x => x.Name)) //sort here
{
   tool.Display();
}
```